# Modifying a datatable within a dataset

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a dataset with 4 data tables in it. I have a requirement to modify one of the data tables. When I try to do so, I end up with an error that says "Property or indexer 'DataTableCollection.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

This is the declaration of the dataset
public DataSet Risk { get; set; }

The below line throws the error
Risk.Tables[0] = matrixSource;

Answer (score 0):

Remove the old table and assign the new

```
Risk.Tables.RemoveAt(0);
Risk.Tables.Add(matrixSource);
```

Comment: I need matrixsource to be the first datatable in the dataset, which can be accessed using Risk.Tables[0].